# How to get a really periodic polar surface plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

Sample data:

```
mydata="theta,rho,value
0,0.8400000,0.0000000
40,0.8400000,0.4938922
80,0.8400000,0.7581434
120,0.8400000,0.6675656
160,0.8400000,0.2616592
200,0.8400000,-0.2616592
240,0.8400000,-0.6675656
280,0.8400000,-0.7581434
320,0.8400000,-0.4938922
360,0.8400000,0.0000000
0,0.8577778,0.0000000
40,0.8577778,0.5152213
80,0.8577778,0.7908852
120,0.8577778,0.6963957
160,0.8577778,0.2729566
200,0.8577778,-0.2729566
240,0.8577778,-0.6963957
280,0.8577778,-0.7908852
320,0.8577778,-0.5152213
360,0.8577778,0.0000000
0,0.8755556,0.0000000
40,0.8755556,0.5367990
80,0.8755556,0.8240077
120,0.8755556,0.7255612
160,0.8755556,0.2843886
200,0.8755556,-0.2843886
240,0.8755556,-0.7255612
280,0.8755556,-0.8240077
320,0.8755556,-0.5367990
360,0.8755556,0.0000000
0,0.8933333,0.0000000
40,0.8933333,0.5588192
80,0.8933333,0.8578097
120,0.8933333,0.7553246
160,0.8933333,0.2960542
200,0.8933333,-0.2960542
240,0.8933333,-0.7553246
280,0.8933333,-0.8578097
320,0.8933333,-0.5588192
360,0.8933333,0.0000000
0,0.9111111,0.0000000
40,0.9111111,0.5812822
80,0.9111111,0.8922910
120,0.9111111,0.7856862
160,0.9111111,0.3079544
200,0.9111111,-0.3079544
240,0.9111111,-0.7856862
280,0.9111111,-0.8922910
320,0.9111111,-0.5812822
360,0.9111111,0.0000000
0,0.9288889,0.0000000
40,0.9288889,0.6041876
80,0.9288889,0.9274519
120,0.9288889,0.8166465
160,0.9288889,0.3200901
200,0.9288889,-0.3200901
240,0.9288889,-0.8166465
280,0.9288889,-0.9274519
320,0.9288889,-0.6041876
360,0.9288889,0.0000000
0,0.9466667,0.0000000
40,0.9466667,0.6275358
80,0.9466667,0.9632921
120,0.9466667,0.8482046
160,0.9466667,0.3324593
200,0.9466667,-0.3324593
240,0.9466667,-0.8482046
280,0.9466667,-0.9632921
320,0.9466667,-0.6275358
360,0.9466667,0.0000000
0,0.9644444,0.0000000
40,0.9644444,0.6512897
80,0.9644444,0.9997554
120,0.9644444,0.8803115
160,0.9644444,0.3450427
200,0.9644444,-0.3450427
240,0.9644444,-0.8803115
280,0.9644444,-0.9997554
320,0.9644444,-0.6512897
360,0.9644444,0.0000000
0,0.9822222,0.0000000
40,0.9822222,0.6751215
80,0.9822222,1.0363380
120,0.9822222,0.9125230
160,0.9822222,0.3576658
200,0.9822222,-0.3576658
240,0.9822222,-0.9125230
280,0.9822222,-1.0363380
320,0.9822222,-0.6751215
360,0.9822222,0.0000000
0,1.0000000,0.0000000
40,1.0000000,0.6989533
80,1.0000000,1.0729200
120,1.0000000,0.9447346
160,1.0000000,0.3702890
200,1.0000000,-0.3702890
240,1.0000000,-0.9447346
280,1.0000000,-1.0729200
320,1.0000000,-0.6989533
360,1.0000000,0.0000000"
```

read in a data frame:

```
foobar <- read.csv(text = mydata)
```

You can check (if you really want to!) that the data are periodic in the `theta` direction, i.e., for each given `rho`, the point at `theta=0` and `theta=360` are precisely the same. I would like to plot a nice polar surface plot, in other words an annulus colored according to `value`. I tried the following:

```
library(viridis) # just because I very much like viridis: if you don't want to install it, just comment this line and uncomment the scale_fill_distiller line
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = theta, y = rho, fill = value)) +
geom_tile() + 
coord_polar(theta = "x") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 45), limits=c(0,360)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
# scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Oranges")
scale_fill_viridis(option = "plasma")
```

I'm getting:

[image]

Yuck! Why the nasty hole in the annulus? If I generate a `foobar` data frame with more rows (more `theta` and `rho` values) the hole gets smaller. This isn't a viable solutione, both because computing data at more rho/theta values is costly and time-consuming, and both because even with 100x100=10^4 rows I still get a hole. Also, with a bigger dataframe, `ggplot` takes forever to render the plot: the combination of `geom_tile` and `coord_polar` is incredibly inefficient. Isn't there a way to get a nice-looking polar plot without unnecessarily wasting memory & CPU time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: all value of `data` for theta=360 were removed (repeat from the values of theta=0)

```
   ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = theta, y = rho, fill = value)) +
      geom_tile() + 
      coord_polar(theta = "x",start=-pi/9) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 45))
```

I just removed `limits` from `scale_x_continuous`
That gives me:
[image]

Comment: ?!? Running your same code gives me the picture I added, which is wrong because 360 and 0 are two different grid lines. How's possible that the same code produces different results? I will add my version of R, Rstudio, ggplot...maybe it's different from yours?

Comment: The fault's on me. I made a modification to the dataframe that I forgot to report. I removed the values for theta=360 (it's a repetition of the info at theta=0 as you said)

Comment: whew, you had me worried there :) I suggest to add that step in your answer. Also, the fact that the 0 grid line isn't vertical is not too nice. By trial and error, I found that `coord_polar(theta = "x", start = -20*pi/180)` does the job (no idea why it works).

Comment: I edited to highlight the fact that I did modify the data. You're right `start= -pi/9` does the trick making it straight but I don't understand it either.